# php display images within folders and subfolders

Tags: php

How would I display all images within subfolders, like this: $dir = array('images/posters', 'images/designs', 'images/illustrations'); ??

code:

```
<?php
     $dir = 'img/werk/';
     $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

     if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
         echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
     } else {
     $dir_content = scandir($dir);

     foreach ($dir_content as $file) {
         $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

         if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' 
                           && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
             echo '<div class="thing large"><div class="item_description">Item description</div><img src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" /></div>';
         }
       }
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have taken a folder and displayed all the images within it and displayed it on a webpage. (all in php)

The code takes the image (from diffrent formats) and puts them on the webpage with the file name under it.

```
$files = glob($root."Images/*.*");
echo '<table width="750px" id="autoimage" align="center">';
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
echo '<tr height="20px"><td colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td width="325px" align="center">';
if(isset($files[$i])){
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img width="300px" src="'.$num.'" alt="Image" />'."<br /><br />";
    $num1 = str_replace($root.'Images/', '', $num);
    if (strpos($num1,'.png') == true) 
    {
        $text = str_replace('.png', '', $num1);
    }
    if (strpos($num1,'.jpeg') == true) 
    {
        $text = str_replace('.jpeg', '', $num1);
    }
    if (strpos($num1,'.jpg') == true) 
    {
        $text = str_replace('.jpg', '', $num1);
    }
    if (strpos($num1,'.tiff') == true) 
    {
        $text = str_replace('.tiff', '', $num1);
    }
    if (strpos($num1,'.gif') == true) 
    {
        $text = str_replace('.gif', '', $num1);
    }
    print "<p>".$text."</p><br />";
}
echo '</td></tr><tr height="20px"><td colspan="2"></td></tr><tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

To get the sub folders, do a similar thing but change the location the code is looking at.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is good code but I've already solved it with work arounds :) Love this forum